# Radially symmetric solution to the wave equation in a 3+1 dimension using D'Alembert formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need help proving this equation which is a [radially symmetric solution to the wave equation in a 3+1 dimension  using D'Alembert formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdQmI.png). I am totally clueless as to how prove it. Thank you.

Comment: Please use latex (mathjax) next time ([see here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard wave equation is: $$ \Delta u = c^2 \partial_{tt} u $$
Since we are dealing with radial symmetry, let's go into spherical coordinates, where:
$$ \Delta u = u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r}u_r + \frac{1}{r^2\sin(\theta}\partial_\theta \left[ \sin(\theta)u_\theta \right] + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2(\theta)}u_{\phi\phi} $$
with $\partial_k u = u_k$.
Let's assume $u$ is radially symmetric. Then $u$ will not change as $\theta$ and $\phi$ change; hence, $u_\theta=u_\phi=0$.
Thus, the new wave equation can be written:
\begin{align}
u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r}u_r &= c^2u_{tt} \\
ru_{rr} + 2u_r &= c^2r u_{tt} \\
\partial_r(ru_r + u) &= c^2 \partial_{tt}(ru) \\
\partial_{rr}(ru) &= c^2\partial_{tt}(ru)
\end{align}
Let $\tilde{u}=u\,r$. Then the last equation above is just the standard 1D wave equation in $\tilde{u}$.

Thus, the solution (by D'Alembert) is:
$$
\tilde{u}(r,t) = \frac{1}{2}[\tilde{f}(r-ct) +\tilde{f}(r+ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int\limits_{r-ct}^{r+ct} \tilde{g}(s)\,ds
$$
Then:
\begin{align}
\tilde{u}(r,0)&=\tilde{f}(r) \implies u(r,0)=\frac{1}{r}\tilde{f}(r)=f(r)\implies f(r\pm ct) = (r\pm ct)^{-1}\tilde{f}(r\pm ct)\\
\tilde{u}_t(r,0)&=\tilde{g}(r)\implies u_t(r,0)=\frac{1}{r}\tilde{g}(r) = g(r)\implies g(s) = (s)^{-1}\tilde{g}(s)
\end{align}
So let's substitute these in:
$$
ru(r,t) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ (r-ct)f(r-ct) + (r+ct)f(r+ct) \right] + \frac{1}{2c}\int\limits_{r-ct}^{r+ct} s{g}(s)\,ds
$$
and divide by $r$ to get the result:
$$
u(r,t) = \frac{1}{2r}\left[ (r-ct)f(r-ct) + (r+ct)f(r+ct) \right] + \frac{1}{2cr}\int\limits_{r-ct}^{r+ct} s{g}(s)\,ds
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved a life :)

Comment: Couldn't find a nice and succinct answer like this anywhere else.